# Random sampling from a large dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

There's a large database from which I have extracted a study population.  For comparison purposes, I would like to select a control group that has similar characteristics.  The two criteria on what I would like to match are age and gender.  The query to give me the numbers that I want for matching purposes is

```
select sex, age/10 as decades,COUNT(*) as counts
        from
        (
            select distinct m.patid
                ,m.sex,DATEPART(year,min(c.admitdate)) -m.yrdob as Age
                from members as m
                inner join claims as c on c.patid=m.PATID
                group by m.PATID, m.sex,m.yrdob
        )x group by sex, Age/10
```

with a result set that looks like

[image]

The decades column in this age is given by the expression

```
(DATEPART(year,min(c.admitdate)) -m.yrdob)/10
```

and this is used to find people in the age ranges of 20-29, 30-39 etc using integer division.  From a larger dataset I would like to select, for instance, 507 females who are in their 20s.  The query to find the characteristics of the larger dataset is

```
select distinct m.patid
        ,m.sex
        ,(DATEPART(year,min(c.admitdate)) -m.yrdob)/10 as decades
        from members as m
        inner join claims as c on c.patid=m.PATID
        group by m.PATID, m.sex,m.yrdob
```

EDIT: results from second query
[image]

So I need the `sum` of the decades column in the second query to equal `counts` in the first query.  What I tried (and returned zero results) is below.  What do I need to do to match these ages?

query that runs, but returns no results:

```
select x.PATID--,x.sex,x.decades,y.counts
    from
    (

    select distinct m.patid
        ,m.sex
        ,(DATEPART(year,min(c.admitdate)) -m.yrdob)/10 as decades
        from members as m
        inner join claims as c on c.patid=m.PATID
        group by m.PATID, m.sex,m.yrdob
    ) as x 
    inner join 
    (

        select sex, age/10 as decades,COUNT(*) as counts
        from
        (
            select distinct m.patid
                ,m.sex,DATEPART(year,min(c.admitdate)) -m.yrdob as Age
                from members as m
                inner join claims as c on c.patid=m.PATID
                group by m.PATID, m.sex,m.yrdob
        )x group by sex, Age/10
    ) as y on x.sex=y.sex and x.decades=y.decades
    group by y.counts,x.PATID,x.sex,y.sex
    having SUM(x.decades)=y.counts and x.sex=y.sex
```

Comment: Try to factor out sub-queries into temp tables so you can examine their contents. That helps with debugging. It will make it obvious why the join does not return anything.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at that.  I knew this query wasn't going to return what I wanted, but it was my best shot! :)

Comment: I cannot make sense of your question.  What tables contain your sample and what tables contain the larger data?  Why "[Do you] need the sum of the decades column in the second query to equal counts in the first query?"  Why would you be summing decades anyway and then comparing them to counts?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the larger data is housed by another company, I wanted to give them a query to run to make sure that the results returned were correct.  My initial idea was to sum the occurrences of, say, males, with a decade of 1 and have it equal 158.  Then it dawned on me, I should just join the two dang queries togeter.  See my posted answer for what I was getting at.

Comment: I think you just need to remove PatId from the final `group by` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff see my answer for what I was trying to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
   T1.sex,
   T1.decades,
   T1.counts,
   T2.patid

from (

   select 
      sex, 
      age/10 as decades,
      COUNT(*) as counts
   from (

      select  m.patid,
         m.sex,
         DATEPART(year,min(c.admitdate)) -m.yrdob as Age
      from members as m
      inner join claims as c on c.patid=m.PATID
      group by m.PATID, m.sex,m.yrdob
   )x 
   group by sex, Age/10
) as T1
join (
   --right here is where the random sampling occurs
    SELECT TOP 50--this is the total number of peolpe in our dataset
      patid
      ,sex
      ,decades

   from (
      select  m.patid,
         m.sex,
         (DATEPART(year,min(c.admitdate)) -m.yrdob)/10 as decades
      from members as m
      inner join claims as c on c.patid=m.PATID
      group by m.PATID, m.sex, m.yrdob

   ) T2
      order by NEWID()
) as T2
on T2.sex = T1.sex
and T2.decades = T1.decades
```

EDIT: I had posted another question similar to this in which I found that my results weren't in fact random, but they were only the TOP N results.  I had ordered by `newid()` in the outermost query and all that was doing was shuffling around the exact same result set.  From a question that is now closed, I found out that I needed to use the `TOP` keyword along with `order by newid()` in the commented line in the above query.