# NewID() not returning a random a sample

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random sampling from a large dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627486/random-sampling-from-a-large-dataset)

I posted a question earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627486/random-sampling-from-a-large-dataset)

And I thought that everything was fine and dandy, but when I went to check out the randomness of the result, I found that there was none.  The other aspects of the query work fine, but I'm getting the `top X` number from the table, regardless of what I try to do.  Since SQL Server doesn't allow you to use an order by clause in a subquery, how can I get around this to make sure that I'm getting a truly random sample?

Comment: @juergend should I amend that question to expound on my new-found problem and close this question?

Comment: If your question is about the same issue then you should not ask another question. Edit your last question. By doing so it will be pushed in the active questions queue.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie . . . The earlier question did not have an `order by` or `top` in the query.  I would suggest that you delete this question.  Then, re-ask the question, including the query and other relevant information.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried to delete, but it was flagged by an admin and I can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY` in a subquery so long as you specify a `TOP` clause.

The old trick was to use `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ... ORDER BY NEWID()` in your subquery to fool the optimizer into materializing the subquery mid-query.

High level folks on the SQL optimizer team have since said that the optimizer now knows that will return all rows an ignore it (though it's still worth a shot)

If that fails, try `SELECT TOP 2147483647 ... ORDER BY NEWID()` to accomplish the same thing as `TOP 100 PERCENT`

Comment: why max int? just because it's a very large number?

Comment: Exactly. Basically just a finite value to satisfy the optimizer that may as well be 100 percent

Comment: interesting, thanks.  this works.  Can you tell me why the way that I had didn't work?

Comment: Or you can try "SEELCT TOP 1E2" as well.